# Can't update image in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to update image for ImageField but it won't update it's keep using

Here is my code

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank = True)
    ownerName = models.CharField(max_length = 30,blank = True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2,blank = True)
    p_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_pics',default = 'dafault1.jpg')
    p_detail = models.CharField(max_length = 200,blank = True)
    p_price = models.CharField(max_length = 6,default = 0)
```

**addproduct in views.py**

```
def addproduct(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tempUser = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)
        temp = request.POST.copy()
        tempProduct = Product()
        pro_form = ProductUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if pro_form.is_valid():
            tempProduct.pName = temp.get('product_name')
            tempProduct.p_detail = temp.get('product_detail') #Detail of product
            tempProduct.p_price = temp.get('product_price')
            tempProduct.ownerName = tempUser.first_name   #ชื่อของคนลงขาย
            tempProduct.save()
            tempOwner = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk) 
            tempProduct.owner.add(tempOwner)
            return redirect('myshop')

    else:   
        pro_form = ProductUpdateForm()
    return render(request, 'trader/addproduct.html',{
        'pro_form':pro_form
    })
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['p_image']
```

**addproduct.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add Product</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Product here</h1>
    <br>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "{% url 'addproduct' %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ pro_form }}<br>
        <label for="product_name">กรุณาใส่ชื่อสินค้า</label> <br>
        <input type="text" id ="product_name" name ="product_name"><br>
        <label for="product_detail">รายละเอียดของสินค้า</label> <br>
        <textarea name="product_detail" id="product_detail " cols="20" rows="4"></textarea><br>
        <label for="product_price">กรุณาใส่ราคาของสินค้า</label> <br>
        <input type="text" id ="product_price" name ="product_price"><br>
        <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I think that my problem was the post method is wrong but I don't know how to solve it. Thank you

Comment: is the new image uploaded to the media rout?

Comment: Could you please add code instead of images of code.

Comment: Sorry. I've add the code.

Comment: Please add the code as **text**

Answer (score 0):

To the `addproduct` function in the views.py you need to save the updated image for the product.

Something like this to be included to your existing function:

```
def addproduct(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tempUser = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)
        temp = request.POST.copy()
        tempProduct = Product()
        pro_form = ProductUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if pro_form.is_valid():
            tempProduct.pName = temp.get('product_name')
            tempProduct.p_detail = temp.get('product_detail') #Detail of product
            tempProduct.p_price = temp.get('product_price')
            tempProduct.ownerName = tempUser.first_name   #ชื่อของคนลงขาย
            tempProduct.save()
            tempOwner = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)
            tempProduct.owner.add(tempOwner)
            p_form.save()

            return redirect('myshop')

    else:
        pro_form = ProductUpdateForm()
    

    return render(request, 'trader/addproduct.html',{
        'pro_form':pro_form
    })
```

I would suggest writing the codes instead of the images to make it easier to read.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite the image to the exist row instead it create a new row with image but no product name.

Comment: @oatty8867 I have included the save in the function, could you give it a try